# javafx in browser

Tags: google-chrome, javafx

I've created a simple application from the JavaFX tutorial using netbeans and it works. But when I open the html file it says that I need to install the JavaFX in order to view the content of the page, though it is already installed which is proved by downloading JavaFX from the suggested link and trying to install it again: it writes "The same version of JavaFX is already installed". What's the problem?

Comment: Maybe the JVM of your browser is different from the netbeans JVM

Comment: The latest version is selected 1.7.0

Comment: I've had the same problem with Chrome 17.0.963.46 and JavaFX 2.0.2. JavaFX is definitely installed on my machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and just installed the 32-bit version of JavaFX. Now I can open the HTML file on Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Like Mikera- Chrome doesn't like Javafx, if you got this to work please let the world know. I have heard that re installing Chrome after javafx is installed can work , but I've tried this and it didn't work. I also know that on my Chrome install I can run normal Java Applets, you can check your install  [here on the java website](http://java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp)

Also in Wwindows you might need to make sure the Mozilla Family check box is checked in the Java Control Panel -> Advanced -> Default Browser for Java...

In Linux this meant I had to simple create a symbolic link from my Java install  bin folder to the a Mozilla Plugin folder...

in chrome you can check the "chrome://plugins/" to see if Java Plugin is recognized....

If you have Internet Explorer installed run it in that, even if just to check, it seems to be the most compatible with JavaFX from what I have used it for